# Getting started with AI tools in Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I want to start playing around with AI tools in Python.  I have looked at some of the projects but I find their examples daunting for my limited experience etc.  For example I want to build a way to compare two html tables and build something that allows me to determine if the tables describe the same concepts.  Right now I am doing this with brute force methods for example I have a population of known tables of a particular type.  I find and extract all of the row labels and create a set of unique row labels.  Then I take a new table and compare the row labels in the new table to the row labels in the set and if the intersection of the row labels is sufficiently large I declare it as a table of that particular type.

My reading though suggests I should be able to do something less mechanical and more artful but I am struggling with how to start.

Can anyone point me in the direction of resources that have accessible examples where AI tools are used to solve specific problems.  For example suppose I come across a table in a document I want to see if that table is one of several types of tables that I have already identified.  How do I pass the exemplar tables and then the candidate table for inspection.  How can I specify the attributes of the table(s) that should be considered?

When I look at the documentation and examples for the AI resources I find they are so general I am lost with respect to knowing how to even start.

I added the above after reading the FAQ I think this is a fair question.  I don't want to ask somebody to code pyBrain to read in my sample tables I want to find cases where others have used that or something similar so I can study their code.

Thanks

I am editing this after it was closed.  The traffic on the Q seems it is relevant.  The NLTK is a great place to start.  I got a soft copy of the book from iTunes after figuring out that it was going to be a great resource.  If you need to scan the book before you buy it the whole thing is online [NLTK Book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/book.html) But buy the book if you decide it is useful.

Comment: Look at everything Peter Norvig has on his blog... you specifically are looking for semantically based tf-idf type systems (latent semantic analysis) in my opinion

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: This seems a little narrow given this in the FAQ   However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: The more relevant part of the FAQ here is "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Incidentally, I *can* say that for your tables problem you probably want to use a [Naive Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier). This is often used to classify documents based on what words they contain (the [classic example is a spam filter](http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html)). Classifying a table based on the row names it contains (when you have a training set of classified tables) is precisely the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Robinson suggests using a naive bayes classifier to solve your problem. This is good advice. Check out the [nltk.classify](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#module-nltk.classify) module for implementations of the NB classifier and others.

Comment: Thanks this helps it will be interesting to test to see whether we can improve our success with these tools.  Actually I just clicked on the link and this is perfect.  Thanks I don't know why I missed this in two days of looking